# side by side div centered using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two div's sitting side by side, but are not centered inside of its div but rather stay on the left of its row. I am trying to make it responsive and centered as the screen size is being adjusted here is my code.

```
  <div class="connectdiv">
   <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6" >
     <h2 id="connect"><u>Connect</u></h2> 
       <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/balt_jitsu19/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
       <a href="mailto:baltznunez@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
       <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/armbar1"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-lg"></i></a>
       <a target="_blank" href="http://github.com/baltz1"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
    </div>  



  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6">
   <h2 id="connect"><u>Made With</u></h2>
     <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
     <a href="https://icons8.com"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/icons8/ios7/32/" title="Icons8" width="32" height="32"></a>
     <img src="https://png.icons8.com/gimp/ios7/25/" title="GIMP" width="25" height="25">
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

My Css

```
#connect{
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family:'Oleo Script Swash Caps', cursive;
  text-shadow:5px 1px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size:35px; 
}
.connectdiv{
  padding:20px;
  width:100%;
  margin:5px auto;
}
```

if it helps i have here on codepen https://codepen.io/balt1/pen/VbYweZ?editors=0100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one ... it will work :

```
 <div class="connectdiv">
 <div class="row">  
 <div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-sm-6" >
 <h2 id="connect"><u>Connect</u></h2> 
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/balt_jitsu19/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
   <a href="mailto:baltznunez@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/armbar1"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-lg"></i></a>
   <a target="_blank" href="http://github.com/baltz1"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
</div>  



 <div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-sm-6">
 <h2 id="connect"><u>Made With</u></h2>
 <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
   <a href="https://icons8.com"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/icons8/ios7/32/" title="Icons8" width="32" height="32"></a>
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/gimp/ios7/25/" title="GIMP" width="25" height="25">
 </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: changes : From <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6" > to <div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-sm-6" >

Comment: You can edit your question if you need to add to it instead of commenting on your own answer.

Comment: okay... actually i already answered just mentioning changes for his Convenience.

Comment: I  understand you've answered. I'm letting you know that you can update your answer with new information/changes in the answer itself instead of commenting on your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't applied the `col-sm-6` class properly. Currently it's a quoted string precariously applied to the DIV.

Change

`class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6"`

to

`class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-center`

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="connectdiv">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
    
      <h2 id="connect"><u>Connect</u></h2>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/balt_jitsu19/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
      <a href="mailto:baltznunez@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/armbar1"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-lg"></i></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://github.com/baltz1"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
    
      <h2 id="connect"><u>Made With</u></h2>
      <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
      <a href="https://icons8.com"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/icons8/ios7/32/" title="Icons8" width="32" height="32"></a>
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/gimp/ios7/25/" title="GIMP" width="25" height="25">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many quotes in your div tag after `text-center`.  Change it to:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-sm-6" >
```

Answer (score 1):

you cot some of these " too much
try

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-sm-6">
```

instead of

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6">
```

Answer (score 0):

About extra quotes already was written (`class="col-xs-6 text-center" "col-sm-6"`)
 But one more point, Bootstrap4 hasn't `col-xs-*` class, instead it's `col-*` class for extra small screens!
You need to write `<div class="col-6 text-center">` 
class `col-sm-6` nothing changes, because Bootstrap mobile first!
[Bootstrap4 docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)